# Socket operation on non-socket with zeromq ZMQ_PUB socket

Tags: zeromq

Fairly simple question. I have some code to send a message from a serialised protobuf event (tried also with just a simple char * string). However when i call send i get the error "Socket operation on non-socket". I've tried a lot of things but to no avail.

```
void send_event(tp::Event event, void * z_pub)
{
  assert(z_pub != NULL);

  zmq_msg_t msg;
  int size = event.ByteSize();
  uint8_t sev[size];

  event.SerializeWithCachedSizesToArray(sev);

  int rc = zmq_msg_init_size(&msg, size);

  memcpy(zmq_msg_data(&msg), &sev, size);

  if (zmq_sendmsg(z_pub, &msg, 0) != 0)
    {
      cout << "Send err code: " << " " << zmq_strerror(zmq_errno())  << endl;
    }

  if (zmq_msg_close(&msg) != 0)
    {
      cout << "Closing message err code: " << zmq_strerror(zmq_errno())  << endl;
    }
}
```

With things inited thus:

```
void * z_ctx_pub = zmq_ctx_new();

void * z_pub = zmq_socket(z_ctx_pub, ZMQ_PUB);

if (z_pub == NULL)
  cerr << "Error creating output socket for process" << endl;


if (zmq_bind(z_pub, z_pub_uri.c_str()) != 0)
  {
    cout << "Binding to PUB err code: " << " " << zmq_strerror(zmq_errno())  << endl;
    abort();
  } 
else 
  cout << "Bound to " << z_pub_uri << endl;
```

Edit: I've now moved the init to the same thread that i was doing the send in and i get:

```
Resource temporarily unavailable
```

http://paste.ubuntu.com/5984515/

Comment: Please show how you create and bind `zpub`.

Comment: Thanks should have included that. Note the uri is of the for ipc:///tmp/xyz_1

Comment: What platform are you on? IPC only works in UNIX with POSIX-supported named pipes; it will not work on Windows. Try with tcp, see if that works.

Comment: I'm on Linux of course

Comment: @raffian Is this still true: zmq IPC does not support Windows?